# Running a Docker container, can't find secrets in /run/secrets

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-secrets

I am using `docker compose` to publish my secrets to a container. According to the documentation, the following `docker-compose.yml` file should make my secret available to the container at runtime.

```yaml
services:
  sbd_listener:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: .
    secrets:
      - service_account_key
secrets:
  service_account_key:
    file: ./service_account_key.json
```

My Dockerfile is as follows (I have commented active code out to get a minimal reproduction):

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 rust:latest
COPY gcp_tasks /sbd/gcp_tasks
COPY sbd_listener /sbd/sbd_listener
WORKDIR /sbd/sbd_listener
ARG BUILD_ENV
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
# COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "infinity"]
# RUN cargo build --config=cargo_${BUILD_ENV}.toml --release
# ENTRYPOINT [ "/sbd/sbd_listener/target/release/sbd_listener" ]
```

I am using the following command to build the image:

```bash
docker compose --progress=plain --verbose build --no-cache --build-arg BUILD_ENV="$env"
```

And then when use `docker run <image-id>` to spin up a container, and `docker exec <container-id> ls -al /run`, there is no `secrets` directory. However, I would expect to see a duplicated file in the location `/run/secrets/service_account_key`.

Am I missing something in my `docker compose` step?

The secret is available to the Dockerfile if I nest the `secrets` block inside the `build` block, but I need access to the runtime secret rather than the build time secret.

**UPDATE**

If I use `docker compose up` rather than `docker compose build` followed by `docker run <image-id>`, the secrets are mounted correctly. However, I am attaching the image to a GCE instance template, and at the moment I am not sure how `docker compose up` can work with GCE. So another question could be: what does `docker compose up` do that `docker compose build` doesn't do?